# How to protect blade template language in CKEditor 4?

Tags: regex, laravel, ckeditor, laravel-blade, ckeditor4.x

I am currently using CKEditor as a backend mail template editing panel. After a bit of tweaking I made it to correctly protect php source and {{ }} tags used by Blade templates.

Sadly I noticed that any Blade words as @if @foreach and the others get moved around the text and wrapped in

tags to make them html compliant.

Is there any way I can avoid this behaviour and let these elements be untouched and live in the page as (for example) protected sources?

Maybe a regex you can suggest that may fit all the Blade language strings?

Thanks a lot in advance.
Federico

Comment: It sounds like you're sending and receiving blade tags to the client browser. Doesn't this open you up to a huge security problem? What if a malicious user submits `<?php Schema::drop('users'); ?>` with the template?

Comment: I know it might be a security issue but I am planning to use this as a backend editor with ACL to limit the users allowed to touch those pages.

Comment: Another solution we did was breaking up the template into sections so that we didn't have to expose our template logic (if statements, etc) to the WYSIWYG editor -- perhaps this is a possibility for you?

Answer (score 1):

Our product also needed this sort of mail template tags, so I understand where you're coming from.

We decided not to use Blade tags due to their full PHP support -- the security implications are not pretty.

Instead, we decided to expose blade-like tokens of `{{ foo }}` and {!! bar !!}`, and write a simple parser for them at https://github.com/Piestar/dough -- perhaps it's useful to you.

Comment: It is something very interesting indeed but it also means reinventing the wheel for my current scope. It does lack loops and other control logic, doesn't it?

Comment: Yeah, no logic -- you're right that it doesn't actually answer the question you asked, but I shared in case it was helpful in another way.

Comment: I appreciate that, really. How bad would you think it might be to allow to also replace a @ if @ else @ endif and other tokens with the real php things? I believe not much apart from the stuff within parenthesis that would take a first pass to substitute the variables and a second pass to deal with the logic tokens. Still, CKEditor would need a proper regex to protect all those sources parts.

Comment: I use <?php ?> in my blade templates all the time -- I don't see why that would be bad, and it would reduce the number of things you'd have to protect against.

Comment: Hello Ben, using the php <?> mark is fine as long as the editor doesn't move the tags to respect html structure as for example in a <table> structure: with my current config, if I use a foreach loop between a <table> and <tr>, the foreach call gets moved BEFORE the <table> tag.

Comment: What editor? If an editor is moving your `<?php` statements, that's quite a big bug.

Comment: Currently using CKEditor 4.5.2 (revision 09b0cca).I thought it was an (undesired) default behaviour... I can post the config if you like.

Comment: Ugh.. I wasn't suggesting using `<?php` in CKEditor; exposing raw PHP to the browser is just asking for trouble.

Comment: I know you are not suggesting it. I by the way have no other easy way to build my text containing loops and control structures and the usage in my app is strictly reserved to a specific role.